# jqueryFile upload Plugin is not working IE 8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, jquery-file-upload

I am using the Jquery file upload plugin on a angularjs project and am running into some difficulties with IE8, mainly that nothing is happening!.I don't see add callback is not firing.Works well in FF and Chrome.

The below code works well in Chrome but  in IE 8 nothing is happening.

I have included following plugins in app

```
jquery: 1.11.0
jquery.ui.widget
jquery.iframe-transport:1.8.2
jquery.fileupload:5.41.0
```

Code in the file:

```
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                add: function (e, data) {
                    alert('add');
                    data.submit();
                },
                progress: function (e, data) {
                    alert('progress');
                },
                start: function (e) {
                    alert('start');
                }
            }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                alert('fileuploadadd');
            }).bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
                alert('fileuploadprogress');
            }).bind('fileuploadstart', function (e) {
                alert('fileuploadstart');
            });
```

On selecting the file doesn't firing add callback in IE 8.Any help will be appreciated.